# Can I use CentOS CBS as yum's base repository?

Tags: centos, yum

I found package `python-six-1.9.0-1.el7` on cbs.centos.org, while it is not contained in the base repository in my centos 7.

Is CBS a package repo like others, such as `mirrors.mit.edu/centos`? If so, can I set CBS as a repo to be accessed by yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.

That site looks like a koji build server, and poking around in [here for example](http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/python-six/1.9.0/1.el7/) does not show any of the metadata directories created by `createrepo` or such necessary for `yum` to act on.

A `yum list` shows `python-six` in the base repo for Centos 7, so to pull in a more recent version (plus any deps) you would probably need to maintain a local yum repository (`yum -y install createrepo` and *etc*., more work for you) or find some other repository that hosts more up-to-date versions of those packages (less work but risks random breakage, depending on maintainer of external repo).